Why does the chart get created at the end of the worksheets in Debug but not from the button
I'm doing an Excel macro that automatically create a chart as a sheet (not embedded in one) if a specific cell has a value. I want the charts to be put at the end of the worksheets and when I run the code from the MS VB for Applications IDE (if we can call it that) the code works perfectly fine and put my new charts at the end. But when I click on the button to which my macro is linked, the charts are created but not put at the end but instead just before the sheet the button is on.
Of note is that the first 3 sheets are sheets (not charts) and all the next ones are charts as sheet. The one on which my button is on is the last sheet just before the charts. Is there a possibility that the macro doesn't see the charts as sheet. Even though it'd be strange as it still would put it one before last place and not at the end.
Here's my code:
Sub CreateCharts()

    Call BaseFunctions

    If Not YesNoMessageBox() Then
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Const FIRST_ROW As Integer = 3
    Const LAST_ROW As Integer = 32
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Year")
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = FIRST_ROW To LAST_ROW
        
        Dim nameCell As String
        nameCell = Trim(ws.Cells(i, 3))
        If nameCell = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
        
        DeleteWorksheet (nameCell)
        
        Dim newChart As Chart
        Dim count As Integer
        count = Sheets.count
        Set newChart = wb.Charts.Add2(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count), NewLayout:=True)
        newChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
        newChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(ws.Cells(i, 4), ws.Cells(i, 19))
        newChart.ChartTitle.Text = nameCell
        newChart.Name = nameCell
        newChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 1
        newChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 6
        newChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 1
        newChart.Axes(xlValue).MinorUnit = 0.1
        newChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesMinorMajor)
        newChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesMajor)
        
    Next i
End Sub


I also tried to create the sheet without specifying the location then moving it at the end of the creation but at best I get a message that tells me it's out of range, and at worst Excel crashes.
Replacing
Set newChart = wb.Charts.Add2(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count), NewLayout:=True)
by
'Set newChart = wb.Charts.Add2(NewLayout:=True)
and using
Sheets(nameCell).Move After:=Sheets(count) before Next i

So following what you all wrote, I changed my way of doing thing. I now create the charts in the current sheet then move them later. I will also try to create them as sheet but for not it works.
Here's the relevant parts.
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Year")

ws.Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select

[...]

ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:=nameCell
Sheets(nameCell).Select
Sheets(nameCell).Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)


To my knowledge (not with 365) the reason of this behavior is that when you add a chart as a sheet, the method automatically assign a data range to the chart. When you create a chart before the first sheet the data will be taken from there. Based on this, when you create a chart at the end of the sheets, to be consequent the data will be taken from the last sheet and therefore the chart sheet will be positioned before it. This results in a workaround that if the Add method refer to the last worksheet it doesn't count the positioning defined in the parameters, rather always create before the last sheet.
But after creation with the command below the sheet can be moved to the end.
Set ch = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add (, Sheets(Sheets.Count), , xlChart)
ch.Move , Sheets(Sheets.Count)  


Following what you wrote I changed it and instead of trying to directly generating the chart as a sheet at the end, I made it in the sheet then moved it.

Why isn't a Chart Using the Add2 Method Created As the Last Sheet?

You first add all the charts before the worksheet and move them as required later.
The code worked on my end but it wasn't tested enough.

Main
Sub CreateCharts()

    BaseFunctions

    If Not YesNoMessageBox Then
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Const FIRST_ROW As Integer = 3
    Const LAST_ROW As Integer = 11
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Year")
    
    Dim ch As Chart, srg As Range, NewChartName As Variant
    Dim i As Long, ChartsCount As Long, ReadyToAddChart As Boolean
    Dim WasChartDeleted As Boolean ' set by 'DeleteSheetByName'
    Dim WasChartFormatted As Boolean ' set by 'FormatChart'
    
    For i = FIRST_ROW To LAST_ROW
        
        ReadyToAddChart = False
        
        NewChartName = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
        
        If Not IsError(NewChartName) Then ' no error
            NewChartName = Trim(NewChartName)
            If Len(NewChartName) > 0 Then ' no blank
                ReadyToAddChart = True
                If IsSheetNameTaken(wb, NewChartName) Then ' exists
                    DeleteSheetByName wb, NewChartName, WasChartDeleted
                    If Not WasChartDeleted Then ' not deleted
                        ReadyToAddChart = False
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        
        If ReadyToAddChart Then
            Set ch = wb.Charts.Add2(Before:=ws, NewLayout:=True)
            Set srg = ws.Rows(i).Columns("D:S")
            FormatChart ch, srg, NewChartName, WasChartFormatted
            If WasChartFormatted Then
                ChartsCount = ChartsCount + 1
            End If
        End If
        
    Next i

    If ChartsCount > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To ChartsCount
            ws.Previous.Move After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count - i + 1)
        Next i
    End If
    ' The first chart is selected.

    'ws.Activate

End Sub

Help
Function IsSheetNameTaken( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal SheetName As String) _
As Boolean
    Dim sh As Object
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if sheet doesn't exist
        Set sh = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    IsSheetNameTaken = Not (sh Is Nothing)
End Function

Sub DeleteSheetAdded(ByVal sh As Object)
    If sh Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
        sh.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub DeleteSheetByName( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal SheetName As String, _
        Optional ByRef WasSheetDeleted As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal DisplayFailMessage As Boolean = True)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Sheet"
    
    If Not IsMissing(WasSheetDeleted) Then
        WasSheetDeleted = False ' in the calling procedure ('ByRef')
    End If
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
    On Error GoTo DeleteSheetError ' start error-handing routine
    
    wb.Sheets(SheetName).Delete
    
    If Not IsMissing(WasSheetDeleted) Then
        WasSheetDeleted = True ' in the calling procedure ('ByRef')
    End If
    
ProcExit:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
DeleteSheetError: ' continue error-handling routine
    If DisplayFailMessage Then
        MsgBox "Run-time error]" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
            & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    Resume ProcExit ' end error-handling routine
End Sub

Sub FormatChart( _
        ByVal ch As Chart, _
        ByVal chartSourceRange As Range, _
        ByVal ChartName As String, _
        Optional ByRef WasChartFormatted As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal DisplayFailMessage As Boolean = True)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Format Chart"
    
    If Not IsMissing(WasChartFormatted) Then
        WasChartFormatted = False ' in the calling procedure ('ByRef')
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine
    
    With ch
        .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
        .SetSourceData Source:=chartSourceRange
        .ChartTitle.Text = ChartName
        .Name = ChartName
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 1
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 6
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 1
        .Axes(xlValue).MinorUnit = 0.1
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesMinorMajor)
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesMajor)
    End With

    If Not IsMissing(WasChartFormatted) Then
        WasChartFormatted = True ' in the calling procedure ('ByRef')
    End If

ProcExit:
    If Not WasChartFormatted Then
        On Error Resume Next
            DeleteSheetAdded ch
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    If DisplayFailMessage Then
        MsgBox "Run-time error]" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
            & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    Resume ProcExit ' end error-handling routine
End Sub


I don't know about those two.

Sub BaseFunctions()
    ' ???
End Sub

Function YesNoMessageBox()
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    Answer = MsgBox("Continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2)
    YesNoMessageBox = (Answer = vbYes)
End Function


Double-check that your code is correctly distinguishing between the Sheets collection and the Worksheets collection. I think that Sheets includes both Worksheets, AND charts, and might be a source of confusion.
This in addition to what Black cat wrote :)
